# Using VBA in Excel, how do I get the names of all OLAP Cubes on a server?

Tags: excel, vba, olap, olap-cube

The company creates an OLAP Cube Database for each of our clients.  I keep up with many things using values in the cubes.  Whenever a new client's cube is set up, I add a sheet to the workbook I use, and create a pivot table using that cube.

I want to checks the server for any cubes that may have been added.

I figured something like this would be the best way.

```
For Each Cube in Server.Cubes
    MsgBox Cube.Name
Next Cube
```

I cannot find anything of the sort.  I searched for an answer for a couple of days now.  Any ways to parse through the server looking at the available cubes?

Answer (score 4):

The SSAS Server has [DMVs](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3006/sql-server-2012-analysis-services-ssas-dmvs/) that you can query to determine the number of cubes on a server. Then you can use VBA to compare that to the number of rows in the table before. Follow [these instructions](https://gqbi.wordpress.com/2013/09/04/excel-using-a-custom-mdx-query-in-excel-table/) to make the connection, or see below.

1. Create a new connection in Excel: In the Get External Data section choose From Other Sources -> SQL Server (NOT Analysis Services).
2. Enter connection information for any SQL Server to which you can connect (we'll change this info in a later step).
3. Pick any database and table to which you have access. Move through the wizard and choose Only save connection at the end.
4. Click Connections. Find your connection and click the Properties button.
5. On the Definition tab, update the connnection string to look like

   ```
   Provider=MSOLAP.5;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=SSASDB;Data Source=MyServer\MyInstance;MDX Compatibility=1;Safety Options=2;MDX Missing Member Mode=Error
   ```
6. Change the Command Type to Default
7. Change the command text to the following:

   ```
   SELECT 
   [CATALOG_NAME] AS SSAS_Database_Name,
   [CUBE_NAME] AS Cube_or_Perspective_Name,
   [CUBE_CAPTION] AS Cube_or_Perspective_Caption,
   [CUBE_TYPE] AS Cube_Type,
   [BASE_CUBE_NAME] AS Base_Cube
   FROM 
   $SYSTEM.MDSCHEMA_CUBES
   WHERE
   CUBE_SOURCE=1
   AND
   [BASE_CUBE_NAME] < ''
   ```
8. Click OK and then click Close.
9. Click Existing Connections. Choose your connection.
10. Choose Table on the Import Data Window. Choose to Put your table on a new worksheet.
11. Your table should be in columns A through E. In cell G2 put `Prior Row Count:`
12. In cell G3 put `Current Row Count:`
13. In cell H2 put 0.
14. In cell H3, enter the following formula:

    ```
    =COUNTA(Table_ExternalData_1[SSAS_Database_Name])
    ```
15. Write a macro that copies the value from cell H3 to H2 and then refreshes the data connection for the table. Mine looks like this:

    ```
    Sub UpdateCubeCount()
        Range("H3").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range("H2").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Range("B2").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End Sub
    ```
16. As a bonus, add conditional formatting to cell H3. Format it to have pink background and red text for the rule Cell Value > $H$2.

You end up with something that looks like this:

[image]

Update: If you are looking for the SSAS databases rather than the cubes themselves, you can use this query instead of the one in step 7:

```
SELECT [catalog_name] AS SSAS_Database_Name, [date_modified] 
FROM $system.DBSCHEMA_CATALOGS
```

This would be useful if you can assume you only have one cube per database, which is fairly common.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.  I set up a table using your method above, but it is not what I was looking for.  I may be using the wrong terminology whenever I say "Cube".  The "Cube" that each client has is showing up in the SSAS_Database_Name column, so it is only showing the one that I choose.  How can I have this list show me all of the server's available "Catalogs" or SSAS Databases in column A?  This would be what I need.

Comment: Ok, I put a query at the end that should help you.

Comment: Wow, that did it. Our Database Admin said that this could not be done easily.  I cannot wait to show him this. Thank you so much!

Comment: This method above worked great.  I now use this in many different applications.  Using this same method, is there a way to pull a list of all of the Dimensions and Measures inside the cubes?

Comment: Yes, there are DMVs for measures ($SYSTEM.MDSCHEMA_MEASURES) and dimensions ($SYSTEM.MDSCHEMA_DIMENSIONS). The [link](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3006/sql-server-2012-analysis-services-ssas-dmvs/) in my answer has the queries for them. You can query a particular cube or all cubes on a database.

Comment: I have searched online for a solution to pull out the Measures and Dimensions from all of the catalogs into one list, but I cannot find anything.  Do you know if this is possible?